# Variable name in R with for

Tags: r, database, for-loop, variables, data-science

I am trying to create several data names from a for, but the parameter of the for does not recognize me

```
c.n_vars<-ncol(DATA)

for (i in 3:c.n_vars)
{
    datasets[i] <- ts(DATA[,i],start = c(2009,1),frequency = 12)
}
```

the idea is to create

```
datasets_1
datasets_2
datasets_3....
```

is posible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In R we try not to create lots of similarly named objects. They are difficult to work with and will cause headaches for you later on. Instead we put related objects in lists:

```
c.n_vars <- ncol(DATA)
datasets <- vector(mode = "list",length = c.n_vars - 2)

for (i in 3:c.n_vars){
  datasets[[i]] <- ts(DATA[,i],start = c(2009,1),frequency = 12)
}
```

If you want the list items to have names you can name them:

```
names(datasets) <- paste0("dataset_",1:length(dataset))
```

Comment: Thx.

Starting from the answer what is the method to graph each variable?

plot(data_1$var1,main="B2C",xlab="Fecha",ylab="%B2C",xlim=c(2012,2020),ylim=c(0.02,0.04))

plot(data_1$var2,main="B2C",xlab="Fecha",ylab="%B2C",xlim=c(2012,2020),ylim=c(0.02,0.04))


I used to do it like this

Comment: @redondo Replace `data_1` with `datasets[[1]]` or something equivalent.

Comment: thank you very much, it helped me a lot

in the plot declarations (main =) can be added  i the for?

example: 

for (i in 1:c.n_vars){
plot(datasets[[i]],main=i, xlab="Fecha",ylab="%B2C")


to identify which is the graph corresponding to each variable